# How to set up a paywall with Firebase?

Tags: html, firebase, paypal, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am wanting to restrict access to a portion of my site. When a user that is logged in pays they get access to that area of my site.

I am looking at the easiest way to accomplish this. Saying the word "Paywall" before I know whats involved sounds so easy, but it has become troublesome to figure out. I am not the worlds best coder but can manage.

I have tried to implement Stripe & Firebase with Zapier, but couldn't manage to link logged in users. Also, Zapier only runs every 5 minutes as well and users would have to wait that time to access.

I have tried to implement Stripe & Firebase without Zapier. There isn't much assistance I could find online that didn't involve Angular. I don't really want to use angular.

To summarize: I want the logged in user to click purchase and they pay to get access to a certain area of my website. I want the payment to process and for this to be logged in the Cloud Firestore database.

Comment: How you restrict users is independent of Firebase. Your server checks for the auth cookie.

Comment: My problem isn't the restriction. I don't know how to confirm a purchase has been received and give access?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I was looking for a solution that might be better than the one I already created and found this question.

Here is what I've done:

Setup a Stripe webhook with the address of a Firebase Cloud Function. When triggered by a payment, the cloud function will store the customer information in a Firebase User collection/document/subcollection etc. That User table is linked with Firebase Auth on the uid, so logged in users can be queried to see if they've paid and if so, give them access to the page.

I'm using Nextjs, so the query piece is done with SSR in my case. There are some other bits about using FB session cookies etc for using a Cloud Function to query, but I'll leave it at that for now.